# Sentence Select with replace

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with two columns, `POLIZA` and `TEXTO_LIMPIO`.

In the `TEXTO_LIMPIO` column is a large string and I want to replace some characters.

I was doing it this way:

```
SELECT REPLACE(TEXTO_LIMPIO,'  ','Ø') AS P 
FROM M_POL 
WHERE POLIZA = '6.015.883'
```

But I get this error:

> The text data type of the argument is not valid for argument 1 of the
>   replace function.

Comment: Please include the table definition with the data types of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `REPLACE`-function on columns with `text`-datatype.

But you can convert it first and then replace:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(max), TEXTO_LIMPIO),' ','Ø') AS P
FROM M_POL
WHERE POLIZA = '6.015.883'
```